# Scramble text in PERL

Tags: regex, perl

is there an automatic way to generate a decoder key and scramble the text (in ASCII) and be able to retrieve it? For example,

```
the dog ran to the fox
```

I could make a hash key for a decoder

```
    my %hash = {
    'a' => 'Z"... so on for all the alphabet 
    }
    and do a regex substitution so the the sentence is 
simply being replaced with a 1:1 alphabet key.
```

but I'm wondering if there has already been a module that can build a key at random, encode and be able to decode easily in the future?
As pointed out below what I want is more of obfuscation instead of encryption.
thanks! 
Ahdee

Comment: Do you want encryption (meaning you'd have to store a key) or just obfuscation (you don't need a key, just a decoder)?

Comment: @ikegami yes that is the more correct term obfuscation - that is what I was intending. Thanks.

Comment: Then install `rot13`, or write your own: `perl -e'my %map; @map{"a".."z", "A".."Z"} = ("n".."z", "a".."m", "N".."Z", "A".."M"); print s/([a-zA-Z])/$map{$1}/rg while <>;'`

Answer (score 1):

Usage:

```sh
$ echo abcdef >file

$ crypt genkey >key

$ crypt encrypt --key "$( cat key )" file >file.aes

$ crypt decrypt --key "$( cat key )" file.aes
abcdef
```

`crypt` uses AES with proper padding, salting and chaining:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Crypt::CBC     qw( );
use File::Basename qw( basename );
use Getopt::Long   qw( );


use constant KEY_LENGTH => 32;


sub random_bytes {
    my $n = shift;
    open(my $fh, '<:raw', '/dev/urandom')
        or die("Can't generate random bytes: Can't open /dev/urandom: $!\n");

    read($fh, my $buf, $n)
        or die("Can't generate random bytes: Error reading from /dev/urandom: $!\n");

    close($fh)
        or die("Can't generate random bytes: Error reading from /dev/urandom: $!\n");

    length($buf) == $n
        or die("Internal error");

    return $buf;
}


sub random_bytes_hex {
    my $n = shift;
    return unpack('H*', random_bytes($n));
}


# $key_hex = generate_aes_key_hex();
sub generate_aes_key_hex {
    return random_bytes_hex(KEY_LENGTH);
}


# my $ciphertext_bin = aes_encrypt($key_bin_or_hex, $plaintext_bin);
sub aes_encrypt {
    my  $key                         =    shift;     # 32 random bytes, or 64 random hex characters.
    our $plaintext; local *plaintext = \( shift );   # Bytes (e.g. UTF-8) to encrypt.

    if (length($key) == 2*KEY_LENGTH && $key =~ /^[0-9a-fA-F]*\z/) {
        $key = pack('H*', $key);
    }

    length($key) == KEY_LENGTH
        or die("Invalid key\n");

    utf8::downgrade($plaintext, 1)
        or die("Plaintext contains non-bytes\n");

    my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
        -cipher => 'Rijndael',
        -key    => $key,
        -header => 'salt',
    );

    return $cipher->encrypt($plaintext);
}


# my $plaintext_bin = aes_decrypt($key_bin_or_hex, $ciphertext_bin);
sub aes_decrypt {
    my  $key                           =    shift;     # 32 random bytes, or 64 random hex characters.
    our $ciphertext; local *ciphertext = \( shift );   # Bytes to decrypt.

    if (length($key) == 2*KEY_LENGTH && $key =~ /^[0-9a-fA-F]*\z/) {
        $key = pack('H*', $key);
    }

    length($key) == KEY_LENGTH
        or die("Invalid key\n");

    utf8::downgrade($ciphertext, 1)
        or die("Ciphertext contains non-bytes\n");

    my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
        -cipher => 'Rijndael',
        -key    => $key,
        -header => 'salt',
    );

    return $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext);
}


sub genkey {
    say generate_aes_key_hex();
}


sub encrypt {
    my $key_hex = shift;

    local $/;
    my $plaintext;
    while ( my $file = <> ) {
        $plaintext .= $file;
    }

    say aes_encrypt($key_hex, $plaintext);
}


sub decrypt {
    my $key_hex = shift;

    local $/;
    my $ciphertext;
    while ( my $file = <> ) {
        $ciphertext .= $file;
    }

    print aes_decrypt($key_hex, $ciphertext);
}


sub usage {
    my $prog = basename($0);

    if ( my ($msg) = @_ ) {
        chomp($msg);
        warn("$msg\n");
    }

    warn("Use $prog --help for more information\n");
    exit(1);
}


sub help {
    my $prog = basename($0);

    print("usage: $prog [options] genkey [genkey_options] [--]\n");
    print("       $prog [options] encrypt [encrypt_options] [--] [file]\n");
    print("       $prog [options] decrypt [decrypt_options] [--] [file]\n");
    print("       $prog --help\n");
    print("\n");
    print("       genkey: Generate a key. It's output to stdout.\n");
    print("\n");
    print("       encrypt: Encrypts the contents of the named file or stdin.\n");
    print("       The encrypted contents are output to stdout\n");
    print("\n");
    print("       decrypt: Decrypt the contents of the named file or stdin.\n");
    print("       The decrypted contents are output to stdout\n");
    print("\n");
    print("Global options:\n");
    print("    [none at this time]\n");
    print("\n");
    print("\"genkey\" options:\n");
    print("    [none at this time]\n");
    print("\n");
    print("\"encrypt\" options:\n");
    print("    --key key_hex  (Required)\n");
    print("\n");
    print("\"decrypt\" options:\n");
    print("    --key key_hex  (Required)\n");
    exit(0);
}


{
    Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( posix_default no_ignore_case ));
    Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
        'help|h|?' => \&help,
    )
        or usage();

    defined( my $op = shift(@ARGV) )
        or usage("Invalid number of arguments");

    if ($op eq 'genkey') {
        my $key;
        Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
        )
            or usage();

        @ARGV == 0
            or usage("Invalid number of arguments");

        genkey();
    }
    elsif ($op eq 'encrypt') {
        my $key;
        Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
            'key|k=s' => \$key,
        )
            or usage();

        defined($key)
            or usage("Key required");

        chomp($key);
        length($key) == 2*KEY_LENGTH && $key =~ /^[0-9a-fA-F]*\z/
            or usage("Invalid key");

        encrypt($key);
    }
    elsif ($op eq 'decrypt') {
        my $key;
        Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
            'key|k=s' => \$key,
        )
            or usage();

        defined($key)
            or usage("Key required");

        length($key) == 2*KEY_LENGTH && $key =~ /^[0-9a-fA-F]*\z/
            or usage("Invalid key");

        decrypt($key);
    }
    else {
        usage("Invalid operation");
    }
}
```